# How to read some data from txt using shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file in Linux like this:

```
//data.txt
    a
    e
    i
    o
    u
```

And wanted to make 5 txt file respect to the characters above with the output look like this:

```
Created a.txt
Created e.txt
Created i.txt
Created o.txt
Created u.txt
```

But I am not sure what I have done wrong, it just stays there and waits for my input.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$data.txt | tr -d '\r'
for((i=0;i<${#x};i++));
do
   y=${x,i,1}
   touch $y.txt
   echo "Created $y.txt"
done
```

Comment: ...so `data.txt` has one character per line... are the spaces shown above it in the question real/accurate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to loop through the file.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
    line=${line%$'\r'}
    if [ -n "$line" ]
    then
        touch "$line".txt
        echo "Created $line.txt"
    fi
done < data.txt
```

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: But in this case they're filenames, so there really shouldn't be any spaces that will cause word splitting. Also, blank lines should be ommitted to avoid created a file called `.txt`. So, I don't see the issue in this case.

Comment: ...best practices for reading files line-by-line are documented in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Unquoted command substitution (using backticks or more modern `$(...)`) does considerably more than split on backticks.

Comment: Filenames absolutely can contain spaces -- they can contain any character other than the NUL. I have a horror story about a bug in a non-shell piece of software causing an unusual filename to be created that led to the deletion of a former employer's backups... (I wasn't in the ops team, but I *was* the person who was notoriously picky about telling people to quote their shell scripts, so I got *years* of I-told-you-so mileage out of that incident).

Comment: I wear a security hat professionally these days. Code that makes assumptions that data values will only be what they *should* be, as opposed that they'll only be what they *can* be, is the stuff that successful red team exercises and CTF victories are made of.

Comment: Deleted my answer since you've addressed the issues in this one. The only thing I'd still note is that the OP had an attempt at trimming trailing carriage returns in their original code; perhaps add a `line=${line%$'\r'}` to take care of that?